# Nome de método variável

Tags: php

Já tive esta dúvida antes mas deixei para lá, agora pergunto:

Exemplo, tenho 1 função:

```
public function nome_variavel(){
    // A função em si nunca muda, preciso apenas que o nome que ela é definida seja variável.
}
```

Gostaria de definir esta função através de um nome variável, exemplo:

```
$nome_da_funcao = "nome_generico";
public function $nome_da_funcao(){} // Apenas exemplo para entendimento
```

> Isso é possível? Se sim, de que forma?

Comment: chamar ou definir? No exemplo citado você define uma função, o que contradiz o que você perguntou anteriormente.

Comment: não exatamente do modo que você está querendo, mas talvez [funções anônimas](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.anonymous.php) sirva para você. O que acha?

Comment: Sim, talvez você queira reformular e limitar o escopo da sua questão.

Comment: Seria útil se você disse o porquê de você precisar disso e em que casos isso é necessário. Dessa forma é mais fácil delinear.

Comment: Não vi seus fontes, mas certamente você está fazendo isso inapropriadamente, não é possível que seja necessário criar um nova função para cada novo cliente. Em todo caso, talvez você queira dar uma olhada no método mágico chamado [__call()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call), e a partir dela, invocar/delegar a/para função cujo bloco você diz nunca mudar. Informe se isso resolve seu caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que isto não seja possível e mesmo que fosse acho que não seria uma pratica muito legal.

Se entendi o [seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95820/nome-de-m%C3%A9todo-vari%C3%A1vel/95854#comment194349_95820), eu recomendo você talvez criar uma `array` associativa, vou tentar formular um exemplo, sei que não é o formato que esta usando, mas deve ajudar.

> Requer 5.3.0 ou superior

*app.php*

```
class App
{
     private $views = array();

     public function page($nome, $function)
     {
           if (is_callable($function)) {
               $this->view[$nome] = $function;
           }
     }

     public function exec()
     {
           $page = $_GET['page'];

           if (empty($this->views[$page]) === false) {
                $caller = $this->views[$page];
                $caller();//Executa método
           }
     }
}
```

*index.php*

```
<?php
require_once 'app.php';

$app = new App;
$app->page('nome_generico', function() {
    echo 'Olá mundo';
});
$app->page('sobre', function() {
    echo 'Eu sou Thyago';
});
$app->page('foo', function() {
    echo 'Algo aqui';
});
$app->exec();
```

- Quando acessar `http://localhost/projeto/?page=nome_generico` é exibido isto:

  > Olá mundo
- Quando acessar `http://localhost/projeto/?page=sobre` é exibido isto:

  > Eu sou Thyago
- Quando acessar `http://localhost/projeto/?page=foo` é exibido isto:

  > Algo aqui

Comment: Ow Guilherme, é exatamente isso! Como nunca utilizei nada do tipo, vim aqui justamente para saber se haveria algo nativo, de qualquer forma pensei em não mexer na estrutura de actions do framework, porém realmente seria impossível, mas este caminho era tudo que precisava como alternativa, muito bem explicada e detalhada sua resposta.

Comment: @ThyagoThySofT não sei se faz diferença pra ti, mas tinha dois erro no script, eu corrigi.

Comment: Claro que faz, para mim e para quem quiser fazer algo assim como eu rs. Na verdade ainda não testei, farei o teste amanhã, mas já deu pra ver que a condição não verificava nada em empty. Muito obrigado Guilherme!